# Are questions of the following form appropriate?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, asking-questions

Consider a question of the following form.

> I have an idea about XXX...
>
> ---Description of Idea---
>
> Can you spot anything incoherent, illogical, or especially problematic about this
>   idea?

Do questions such as this belong here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we've ever made an official policy on those kinds of questions; we have allowed them, historically, although typically only those with short, concise problems. If one was to ask us to spot a flaw in an entire research paper or something, that would be a different story. The key is keeping it to a reasonably scoped question where you are focusing on the logical form of a single argument.

Comment: You mean I can't get Philosophy.SE to proofread my dissertation for me?